# DBUnit ignores xml element

Tags: java, xml, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, dbunit

I am using DBUnit (version 2.4.9) for loading the data for integration tests. I'm getting a weird problem that 1 field (`deleted`) is **not being set** in the DB (postgres).

Here is my XML data load:

```
<dataset>
    ...
    <workgroup id="100" created="2013-10-08 14:15:00.000" deleted="2013-10-08 14:15:00.000" version="0" name="Name1" org_id="100"/>
    ...
</dataset>
```

Here is my schema definition:

```
CREATE TABLE workgroup
(
  deleted timestamp without time zone,
  ... some constraints
)
```

All other fields are being set-up correctly. Any ideas what can be causing this? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I narrowed down the problem and it has to do something with entries in XML file order. If I have:

```
<workgroup id="101" version="0" name="Name1"/>
<workgroup id="100" version="0" name="Name1" deleted="2013-10-08 />
```

it doesn't work, but this:

```
<workgroup id="100" version="0" name="Name1" deleted="2013-10-08 />
<workgroup id="101" version="0" name="Name1"/>
```

works correctly. DBUnit bug?

**EDIT:**
Another example, that I cannot overcome:

```
<organisation id="1"/>
<organisation id="2" parent_id="1"/>
```

Organisation needs to exists before we can assign it value, so workaround, like this:

```
<organisation id="2" parent_id="1"/>
<organisation id="1"/>
```

will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is a "feature" of dbunit. To avoid this behavior you must provide a dtd to define the columns.

```
<!ATTLIST organisation  
    id CDATA #REQUIRED  
    parent_id CDATA #IMPLIED  
>
```

Answer (score 3):

The "feature" of dbUnit is that the first line defines the columns, then the undeclared columns in second line are ignored !

The solution is in 2 steps:

- have all columns in the first line(also in all previous dbunit files). Like in your workAround
- use ReplacementDataSet to set "null" in needed columns

the dataset.xml

```
  <organisation id="1" parent_id="[null]"/>
  <organisation id="2" parent_id="1"/>
```

AND the trick to set the columns to null in your java test class

```
@Override
protected IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception {
  FlatXmlDataSetBuilder flatXmlDataSetBuilder = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder();
  IDataSet ds = flatXmlDataSetBuilder.build(getClass().getResource("dataset.xml"));
  ds = new ReplacementDataSet(ds);
  ((ReplacementDataSet) ds).addReplacementObject("[null]", null);

  return ds;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would work. But it's more messy then providing dtd file.

Comment: @FazoM yes, this is a more "Java" approach.